# My kittens keep fighting!!

Tags: cats, aggression, biting, scratching

About a month ago we bought our kitten ( Missy ) she's a really playful girl, a little bit to playful. She was forever biting us and scratching, running around the room, she can't go out for another 3 months as she's not neutered, so we thought we should buy another kitten so she has another playmate, in the hope she would stop biting us ! 
We bought our new kitten ( Scoobie ) yesterday, we bought a male as they are supposed to get on better this way. 
I will admit, we didn't introduce them correctly, we just sat the down together and hoped for the best, we separated them at night however. 
Our new little scoobie is a couple weeks younger than Missy - Missy is around 12 weeks, Scoobie is about 9. 
Scoobie is a very calm and loving cat, I think he is still in the sleepy kitten stage. I can't work out if Missy is trying to fight or play with Scoobie, but she has no boundries, so if Scoobie squeals a little she pulls back for a minute then continues. 
What can we do? Missy is just to rough with Scoobie, but Scoobie still goes up to her wanting to play and interact, so he's not scared of her? However he can't catch a break as Missy won't leave him alone ! Only when he eats ( in a separate part to her) she allows it.
Missy does bite and do that rabbit kick with her back legs on Scoobie, which we try to break up and distract Missy with toys ( which doesn't work ) We have tried to put them in separate rooms, mainly putting Scoobie in a room so Missy still has her 'house' but then Scoobie constantly cries and Missy almost forgets that Scoobie is in there so doesn't pay attention to the door or him!

I have read to leave them to it if they are hissing or boxing each other, but I get worried when little Scoobie makes a noise.

Do we start all over again and try to introduce them through the doors